# Error creating multiple docker instances of CouchDB

Tags: docker, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I have been trying to create two docker CouchDB instances for two peer in a single host ( node1) . However, only one of the peers and one couchdb instance starts up whereas the other one exits in 'n' seconds. This is how my docker-compose-node1.yml file looks like:

```
peer2.example:
  container_name: peer2.example
  extends:
    file: docker-compose-peer.yml
    service: peer-base
  environment:
    - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb_peer2:5984
    - CORE_PEER_ID=peer2.example
    - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer2.example:7051
    - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
    - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
  ports:
    - 7051:7051
    - 7053:7053
  volumes:
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/example/peers/peer2.example:/etc/hyperledger/peers
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/example/peers/peer2.example/msp:/etc/hyperledger/peers/msp
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/example/peers/peer2.example/tls:/etc/hyperledger/peers/tls
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/example/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
  depends_on:
    - couchdb_peer2 

couchdb_peer2:
  container_name: couchdb_peer2
  image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
  # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
  # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
  environment:
    - COUCHDB_USER=
    - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    #DB_URL: http://localhost:5984/member_db
  ports:
    - "5984:5984"
  network_mode: "host"

peer4.example:
  container_name: peer4.example
  extends:
    file: docker-compose-peer.yml
    service: peer-base
  environment:
    - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb_peer4:5984
    - CORE_PEER_ID=peer4
    - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer4.example:7050
    - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
    - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
  ports:
    - 8051:7051
    - 8053:7053
  volumes:
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/example/peers/peer4.example:/etc/hyperledger/peers
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/example/peers/peer4.example/msp:/etc/hyperledger/peers/msp
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/example/peers/peer4.example/tls:/etc/hyperledger/peers/tls
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/example/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
depends_on:
    - couchdb_peer4

couchdb_peer4:
  container_name: couchdb_peer4
  image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
  # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
  # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
  environment:
    - COUCHDB_USER=
    - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    #DB_URL: http://localhost:5984/member_db
  ports:
    - "6984:5984"
  network_mode: "host"
```

And this is the error :

```
2018-02-15 19:36:11.359 UTC [couchdb] CreateSystemDatabasesIfNotExist -> ERRO 024 Error during CouchDB CreateDatabaseIfNotExist() for system dbName: _users  error: Couch DB Error:file_exists,  Status Code:412,  Reason:The database could not be created, the file already exists.
2018-02-15 19:36:11.359 UTC [couchdb] VerifyCouchConfig -> ERRO 025 Unable to connect to CouchDB,  error: Couch DB Error:file_exists,  Status Code:412,  Reason:The database could not be created, the file already exists.   Check the admin username and password.
```

I have made the necessary changes in /etc/hosts file, docker-compose-peer.yml, crypto-config.yaml.

This is the command I am using to start up the containers:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-node1.yml up -d peer4.example peer2.example
```

And this is what the docker ps command shows ( removed the container ID column):

```
IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                           PORTS               NAMES
hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            peer2.example
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb   "tini -- /docker-e..."   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            couchdb_peer4
```

What am I missing here. Also please let me know if you need me to post my docker-compose-peer.yml file as well. Thank you

Comment: is there a reason why you are using network_mode=host for the CouchDB containers?  I would remove that from your compose file else I believe that what happens is the peers end up connecting to the same container instance

Comment: I tried changing it to 'bridge' and that didnt help either. Now two of the couchdb instances remain up and running but both the peers exits. This is the error which it is throwing now :
panic: Error in instantiating ledger provider: Unable to connect to CouchDB, check the hostname and port: Get http://couchdb_peer2:5984/: dial tcp: lookup couchdb_peer2 on 10.a.b.c:53: read udp 172.d.e.f:51223->10.a.b.c:53: i/o timeout. 

I am also not sure from where it is fetching the 10.a.b.c IP. Looked into the local.ini file but doesn't look like there is any hard coded IPs there.